# scipy equivalent of numpy.prod() for sparse matrices

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I am looking for an equivalent of [numpy.prod](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.prod.html) to be used with the sparse representations that scipy offers ([scipy.sparse](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html)). Specifically, I'm trying to compute the product along a single axis. I can do it by first converting to dense (`M.todense().prod(axis=0)`), but am looking for something more efficient.

Comment: I don't think there's an equivalent. Most sparse matrices only implement element-wise operations.

Comment: Most if not all values will be 0. The whole row or column will have to be dense, nonzero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For `prod` reduction operation along each column i.e. `axis=0`, we would only have non-zero output for columns that have all non-zeros. We can use that fact to have one custom rolled out version, like so -

```
def sparse_prod_axis0(A):
    # Valid mask of row length that has all non-zeros along each col
    valid_mask = A.getnnz(axis=0)==A.shape[0] # Thanks to @hpaulj on this!

    # Initialize o/p array of zeros
    out = np.zeros(A.shape[1],dtype=A.dtype)

    # Set valid positions with prod of each col from valid ones
    out[valid_mask] = np.prod(A[:,valid_mask].A,axis=0)
    return np.matrix(out)
```

Sample run -

```
In [92]: from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix
    ...: a = np.random.randint(0,4,(5,10))
    ...: A = csr_matrix(a)
    ...: 

In [93]: (A.todense().prod(axis=0))
Out[93]: matrix([[ 0,  0,  6, 48,  0,  0,  0,  0, 72,  0]])

In [94]: sparse_prod_axis0(A)
Out[94]: matrix([[ 0,  0,  6, 48,  0,  0,  0,  0, 72,  0]])
```

Comment: `csr_matrix.getnnz(axis=None)` might be useful; bit `getmmz` uses `bincount`. :)

Comment: @hpaulj Thanks! Much improved now!

Comment: Thanks! I timed it and your function is almost 15x faster than converting to dense.