# numpy.any(axis=i) for scipy.sparse

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

```py
import numpy
a = numpy.array([
    [0, 1, 0, 0],
    [1, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 1, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0],
])
numpy.any(a, axis=0)
numpy.any(a, axis=1)
```

produces

```
array([ True,  True,  True, False])
array([ True,  True,  True, False, False])
```

However, after

```
from scipy import sparse
a = sparse.csr_matrix(a)
```

the same `numpy.any(a, axis)` calls produces

```
<5x4 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.intc'>'
        with 3 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

and

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 5, in any
  File "C:\Users\user\.conda\envs\py385\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py", line 2330, in any
    return _wrapreduction(a, np.logical_or, 'any', axis, None, out, keepdims=keepdims)
  File "C:\Users\user\.conda\envs\py385\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py", line 87, in _wrapreduction
    return ufunc.reduce(obj, axis, dtype, out, **passkwargs)
numpy.AxisError: axis 1 is out of bounds for array of dimension 0
```

Of course, `a` is actually so large a sparse matrix that converting to normal `numpy` array is not an option.  How can I acquire the same (or equivalent) result for a `csr_matrix` and other `scipy.sparse` matrices?

**ADDED:**

According to [Usage information in official scipy documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html#usage-information),

> Despite their similarity to NumPy arrays, it is **strongly discouraged** to use NumPy functions directly on these matrices because NumPy may not properly convert them for computations, leading to unexpected (and incorrect) results. If you do want to apply a NumPy function to these matrices, first check if SciPy has its own implementation for the given sparse matrix class, or **convert the sparse matrix to a NumPy array** (e.g., using the *toarray()* method of the class) first before applying the method.

I'm looking for "its own implementation" or equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

you can use sum instead of any on bool arrays

```
import numpy
a = numpy.array([
    [0, 1, 0, 0],
    [1, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 1, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0],
])

from scipy import sparse
a = sparse.csr_matrix(a.astype(bool))
# Use sum instead of any on a bool array
print(a.sum(axis=0).astype(bool))
print(a.sum(axis=1).flatten().astype(bool))
```

output:

```
[[ True  True  True False]]
[[ True  True  True False False]]
```

If you want to do 'all' that would be a little tricky since scipy doesn't appear to have an implementation for 'prod'.
But [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44320865/scipy-equivalent-of-numpy-prod-for-sparse-matrices) has an answer for that case.

Comment: For `all` test the `sum` against the dimension.  If all 5 terms are 1, the sum will be 5.  `prod` will be (nearly) always 0 with sparse (mostly 0s) matrices,

Comment: Thanks, but I was missing a clarification that `a` is of arbitrary numbers, positive or negative.  Since some non-zero elements of a row or column of `a` can be sum to zero, using sum was not enough.  Adding `.astype(bool)` for `a` too solved the problem.