# Heuristic to choose five column arrays that maximise the dot product

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, or-tools, heuristics

I have a sparse 60000x10000 matrix M where each element is either a 1 or 0. Each column in the matrix is a different combination of signals (ie. 1s and 0s). I want to choose five column vectors from M and take the Hadamard (ie. element-wise) product of them; I call the resulting vector the strategy vector. After this step, I compute the dot product of this strategy vector with a target vector (that does not change). The target vector is filled with 1s and -1s such that having a 1 in a specific row of the strategy vector is either rewarded or penalised.

**Is there some heuristic or linear algebra method that I could use to help me pick the five vectors from the matrix M that result in a high dot product?** I don't have any experience with Google's OR tools nor Scipy's optimization methods so I am not too sure if they can be applied to my problem. Advice on this would be much appreciated! :)

Note: the five column vectors given as the solution does not need to be the optimal one; I'd rather have something that does not take months/years to run.

Comment: Interesting problem. Five arbitrary column vectors or five neighbouring ones? Maybe you can show a very small example of what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Five arbitrary columns from M c1, c2, c3, c4, and c5. Each column is filled with 1s and 0s such that a 1 is a signal. Then compute elementwise operation of these columns as this is analogous to the 'and' operator: all columns must have a 1 in a row for there to be a 1 in the resulting vector s for that row. I want to maximise the dot product of s and the target vector s*. Computing all possible combinations of columns that could result in a strategy s is not feasible so I would like a faster solution (that does not need to be the absolute optimal one). Let me know if anything is unclear :)

Comment: Choosing 5 elements from 10,000 elements gives ~10^18 possible combinations. There aren't a lot of great optimization options at this scale unless you can turn this into a convex problem somehow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, thanks for a good question. I don't get to practice numpy that often. Also, I don't have much experience in posting to SE, so any feedback, code critique, and opinions relating to the answer are welcome.

This was an attempt at finding an optimal solution at first, but I didn't manage to deal with the complexity. The algorithm should, however, give you a greedy solution that might prove to be adequate.

[Colab Notebook (Python code + Octave validation)](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1zcY86aPsMxsJXY_qxKZm4_Tn8wojH2pU?usp=sharing)

**Core Idea**

> Note: During runtime, I've transposed the matrix. So, the column vectors in the question correspond to row vectors in the algorithm.

Notice that you can multiply the target with one vector at a time, effectively getting a new target, but with some `0s` in it. These will never change, so you can filter out some computations by removing those rows (columns, in the algorithm) in further computations entirely - both from the target and the matrix. - you're then left with a valid target again (only `1s` and `-1` in it).

That's the basic idea of the algorithm. Given:

- `n`: number of vectors you need to pick
- `b`: number of best vectors to check
- `m`: complexity of matrix operations to check one vector

Do an exponentially-complex `O((n*m)^b)` depth-first search, but decrease the complexity of the calculations in deeper layers by reducing target/matrix size, while cutting down a few search paths with some heuristics.

**Heuristics used**

1. The best score achieved so far is known in every recursion step. Compute an optimistic vector (turn `-1` to `0`) and check what scores can still be achieved. Do not search in levels where the score cannot be surpassed.

   This is useless if the best vectors in the matrix have `1s` and `0s` equally distributed. The optimistic scores are just too high. However, it gets better with more sparsity.
2. Ignore duplicates. Basically, do not check duplicate vectors in the same layer. Because we reduce the matrix size, the chance for ending up with duplicates increases in deeper recursion levels.

**Further Thoughts on Heuristics**
The most valuable ones are those that eliminate the vector choices at the start. There's probably a way to find vectors that are worse-or-equal than others, with respect to their affects on the target. Say, if `v1` only differs from `v2` by an extra `1`, and target has a `-1` in that row, then `v1` is worse-or-equal than `v2`.

The problem is that we need to find more than 1 vector, and can't readily discard the rest. If we have 10 vectors, each worse-or-equal than the one before, we still have to keep 5 at the start (in case they're still the best option), then 4 in the next recursion level, 3 in the following, etc.

Maybe it's possible to produce a tree and pass it on in into recursion? Still, that doesn't help trim down the search space at the start... Maybe it would help to only consider 1 or 2 of the vectors in the worse-or-equal chain? That would explore more diverse solutions, but doesn't guarantee that it's more optimal.

**Warning:** Note that the MATRIX and TARGET in the example are in `int8`. If you use these for the dot product, it will overflow. Though I think all operations in the algorithm are creating new variables, so are not affected.

**Code**

```
# Given:
TARGET = np.random.choice([1, -1], size=60000).astype(np.int8)
MATRIX = np.random.randint(0, 2, size=(10000,60000), dtype=np.int8)

# Tunable - increase to search more vectors, at the cost of time.
# Performs better if the best vectors in the matrix are sparse
MAX_BRANCHES = 3   # can give more for sparser matrices

# Usage
score, picked_vectors_idx = pick_vectors(TARGET, MATRIX, 5)

# Function
def pick_vectors(init_target, init_matrix, vectors_left_to_pick: int, best_prev_result=float("-inf")):
    assert vectors_left_to_pick >= 1
    if init_target.shape == (0, ) or len(init_matrix.shape) <= 1 or init_matrix.shape[0] == 0 or init_matrix.shape[1] == 0:
        return float("inf"), None
    target = init_target.copy()
    matrix = init_matrix.copy()

    neg_matrix = np.multiply(target, matrix)
    neg_matrix_sum = neg_matrix.sum(axis=1)

    if vectors_left_to_pick == 1:
        picked_id = np.argmax(neg_matrix_sum)
        score = neg_matrix[picked_id].sum()
        return score, [picked_id]

    else:
        sort_order = np.argsort(neg_matrix_sum)[::-1]
        sorted_sums = neg_matrix_sum[sort_order]
        sorted_neg_matrix = neg_matrix[sort_order]
        sorted_matrix = matrix[sort_order]

        best_score = best_prev_result
        best_picked_vector_idx = None

        # Heuristic 1 (H1) - optimistic target.
        # Set a maximum score that can still be achieved
        optimistic_target = target.copy()
        optimistic_target[target == -1] = 0
        if optimistic_target.sum() <= best_score:
            # This check can be removed - the scores are too high at this point
            return float("-inf"), None

        # Heuristic 2 (H2) - ignore duplicates
        vecs_tried = set()

        # MAIN GOAL:   for picked_id, picked_vector in enumerate(sorted_matrix):
        for picked_id, picked_vector in enumerate(sorted_matrix[:MAX_BRANCHES]):
            # H2
            picked_tuple = tuple(picked_vector)
            if picked_tuple in vecs_tried:
                continue
            else:
                vecs_tried.add(picked_tuple)

            # Discard picked vector
            new_matrix = np.delete(sorted_matrix, picked_id, axis=0)
            
            # Discard matrix and target rows where vector is 0
            ones = np.argwhere(picked_vector == 1).squeeze()
            new_matrix = new_matrix[:, ones]
            new_target = target[ones]
            if len(new_matrix.shape) <= 1 or new_matrix.shape[0] == 0:
                return float("-inf"), None

            # H1: Do not compute if best score cannot be improved
            new_optimistic_target = optimistic_target[ones]
            optimistic_matrix = np.multiply(new_matrix, new_optimistic_target)
            optimistic_sums = optimistic_matrix.sum(axis=1)
            optimistic_viable_vector_idx = optimistic_sums > best_score
            if optimistic_sums.max() <= best_score:
                continue
            new_matrix = new_matrix[optimistic_viable_vector_idx]
         
            score, next_picked_vector_idx = pick_vectors(new_target, new_matrix, vectors_left_to_pick - 1, best_prev_result=best_score)
            
            if score <= best_score:
                continue

            # Convert idx of trimmed-down matrix into sorted matrix IDs
            for i, returned_id in enumerate(next_picked_vector_idx):
                # H1: Loop until you hit the required number of 'True'
                values_passed = 0
                j = 0
                while True:
                    value_picked: bool = optimistic_viable_vector_idx[j]
                    if value_picked:
                        values_passed += 1
                        if values_passed-1 == returned_id:
                            next_picked_vector_idx[i] = j
                            break
                    j += 1

                # picked_vector index
                if returned_id >= picked_id:
                    next_picked_vector_idx[i] += 1

            best_score = score

            # Convert from sorted matrix to input matrix IDs before returning
            matrix_id = sort_order[picked_id]
            next_picked_vector_idx = [sort_order[x] for x in next_picked_vector_idx]
            best_picked_vector_idx = [matrix_id] + next_picked_vector_idx

        return best_score, best_picked_vector_idx
```

Comment: Thanks for the elaborate response @Morton! I appreciate all the effort you have put in! I think there are a few errors in the code as when I multiply the returned columns elementwise and then take the dot product with the target vector the score is not the same as the one returned. In line 16, you take the sum across each *row* with `neg_matrix.sum(axis=1)`. Should this be `axis=0`? Indeed, the returned `picked_vectors_idx` seems to be rows indices rather than that of columns as sometimes the returned values are outside the bounds of the columns.

Comment: Ah, indeed - I see. I've assumed the number of vectors would be larger than their size, but it's the opposite. I'll see if I can correct that.

Comment: Okay, I believe the implementation is correct with respect to what you mentioned. I forgot to say that I transposed your representation. I find working with row vectors a bit easier.

I just need to change the matrix shape to be `10,000x60,000` and target's to be `60,000`.

And I wish I'd realised that `len(vec) > vec_num` earlier, as that's much faster to compute due to more data being discarded.

Comment: The score the function is giving is still different to the one I calculate when I compute it using the indices returned. I tried using the returned indices to index rows in `MATRIX` and the score was different. Upon trying them to index columns in `MATRIX` I get the error of incorrect shapes when computing the dot product.

Comment: Any chance you could share your input data? (In any form you like). It does sound like I've overlooked something. The score you're getting would also be helpful, just to check my logic. Also, to cover all cases, I hope you remembered to increment my indices by 1, as matlab is 1-indexed, iirc :)

Comment: I used your example input data you have at the top of your code, TARGET and MATRIX. I just multiplied the indices of MATRIX returned elementwise. Then I took the dot product of this result with TARGET. The resulting score was different to the one returned by the function.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235842/discussion-between-morton-and-alex-pharaon).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's too naive, but the first thing that occurs to me is to choose the 5 columns with the shortest distance to the target:

```
import scipy
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import pairwise_distances

def sparse_prod_axis0(A):
    """Sparse equivalent of np.prod(arr, axis=0)
    From https://stackoverflow.com/a/44321026/3381305
    """
    valid_mask = A.getnnz(axis=0) == A.shape[0]
    out = np.zeros(A.shape[1], dtype=A.dtype)
    out[valid_mask] = np.prod(A[:, valid_mask].A, axis=0)
    return np.matrix(out)

def get_strategy(M, target, n=5):
    """Guess n best vectors.
    """
    dists = np.squeeze(pairwise_distances(X=M, Y=target))
    idx = np.argsort(dists)[:n]
    return sparse_prod_axis0(M[idx])

# Example data.
M = scipy.sparse.rand(m=6000, n=1000, density=0.5, format='csr').astype('bool')
target = np.atleast_2d(np.random.choice([-1, 1], size=1000))

# Try it.
strategy = get_strategy(M, target, n=5)
result = strategy @ target.T
```

It strikes me that you could add another step of taking the top few percent from the `M`–`target` distances and check their mutual distances — but this could be quite expensive.

I have not checked how this compares to an exhaustive search.

Comment: Although this seems like a logical first approach the elementwise multiplication of the vectors completely changes their distances from the target. For example, vector c1 may be very far from the target but, when multiplied with the right combination of vectors, result in an optimal strategy s. Since the target vector is sparse, I think for my problem the optimal solution is likely to be a mixture of dense vectors combined with one (max two sparse) ones. Unfortunately, your solution results in five sparse vectors (as target is sparse) that when multiplied result in a too sparse of a vector s.

Comment: I think I should be able to take advantage of the realisation that of the 5 vectors chosen most should be dense and one (max two) should be sparse, but am not entirely too sure how yet.

Comment: So then should the greatest sums (column-wise) not work? I gave it a quick try and it didn't seem to help (replacing `dists` with `np.squeeze(np.asarray(np.sum(M, axis=0)))`).

Comment: `strategy` gives an array where everything is either 'True' or 'False'. I tried indexing the column numbers with `np.where(strategy)[1]` and got the following array when I ran it on your example data. `resulting_array = array([ 35,  52,  79, 355, 415, 417, 436, 495, 537, 549, 663, 686, 728, 737, 787, 814, 823, 832, 835, 925, 963])`. Am I doing something wrong? Should it not be 5 elements in `resulting_array`? Thanks!

Comment: It seems `M[idx]`, which is returned in the second function, selects five *rows* rather than columns as its shape is 5x1000 using your example matrix `M`. I tried changing this to `M[:,idx]` but then it says some of the indices in `idx` are out of range... It seems that in the `get_strategy` function rows are being selected instead of columns. Does `pairwise_distances` calculate the distance between rows rather than columns maybe @kwinkunks?